# Windows SharePoint Services Search missing in Servers in Farm

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

"Windows SharePoint Services Search" is not showing in the my APP server. I checked in WFE als, there also it is not there. I checked in "Services->Windows SharePoint Services Search" is running in all servers. It was shown before. When I am playing around this. I lost it.

How to get back it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install MOSS, the Enterprise search (Office SharePoint Server Search) takes over and the WSS search becomes Windows SharePoint Services Help Search.

Answer (score 3):

Run the SharePoint configuration wizard again. but in your screen shot i'm not seeing anything missing. is it the old screen shot